# Xcode deosn't detect a framework

Tags: iphone

I have added ALAssetsLibrary framework to my project and for some reason XCode doesnt detect it.

I have no code completion, and XCode gives a warning and then crashes when I use the following code

```
ALAssetsLibrary *library = [[ALAssetsLibrary alloc] init];
[library enumerateGroupWithTypes:ALAssetsGroupAlbum
                      usingBlock:assetGroupEnumerator
                    failureBlock:^(NSError *error){
                        NSLog(@"A problem occured");

 }];
```

It doesnt detect what ALAssetsLibrary is and the warning which leads to a crash is

> warning: 'ALAssetsLibrary' may not respond to '-enumerateGroupWithTypes:usingBlock:failureBlock:'

[image]

Why isnt XCode detecting the framework?

I have added it to my project as well as imported it.

[image]

[image]

I would really appreciate the help with this, I dont understand what I did wrong. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you're importing AssetsLibrary.h, are you sure this refers to the class ALAssetsLibrary and ALAssetsGroupAlbum?

Second, I'm not sure it failing to find it is the problem, I imagine there would be a different error in that case, such as, this class is not defined, first use in function.

It's saying unrecognized selector, which means there might be a problem with your pointers.

Answer (score 1):

Choose "Device", not "Simulator".

Answer (score 0):

Have you got your SDK set to 3.x?  Blocks were only introduced in iOS 4.0, along with all the methods relating to them.